# Is there a way to apply Liskov Substitution principle in C++ without violating Open or Close Principle?

Tags: c++

I have this code written in C++. However, looking at the code, I know it will violate the Open or Close Principle. Looking at [Soft Eng StackExchange Answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244773/is-method-overriding-always-a-violation-of-liskov-substitution-principle). The principle is often more broadly (and vaguely) understood that subclasses should not "break expectations" which is certainly a good concept of design, but not really what the LSP says.

```c++
struct Shape {
    virtual xyz area() const = 0;
};
struct Rectangle : Shape {
    Rectangle(const xyz width, const xyz height) : width{width}, height{height} {}
    xyz get_width() const { return width; }
    xyz get_height() const { return height; }
    virtual void setW(const xyz width) { this->width = width; }
    virtual void setH(const uint32_t height) { this->height = height; }
    xyz area() const override { return width * height; }
private:
    xyz width, height;
};
struct Square : Shape {
    Square(xyz size) : sizes(size) {}
    void setS(const xyz size) { this->sizes = size; }
    xyz area() const override { return sizes * sizes; }
private:
    xyz sizes;
};
void process(Shape &s) { }
```

Comment: can you explain how LSP and Open Closed are in contrast in your code? I dont really see what you mean

Comment: In what way will this code violate OCP?  How is it not applying LSP?  May want to separate out the public facing API and the inheritance facing API, using [NVI](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface).

Comment: I don't see how your code is violating OCP, you abstract how the area is calculated so that you it's open to any extension without the need of any modification. I don't even see how this is conflicting with LSP: anywhere you want to use a `Shape` you could use a `Rectangle` or a `Square` since their `area` implementation is correctly implemented (and has a specific meaning).

Comment: it would violate the LSP if Square inherits Rectangle (which is a common example for showing the violation of LSP), due to the setW and setH functions, but this is not the case in your code....